# Parallel computing in C++ with OpenMP brings no difference to elapsed time

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am studying OpenMP. I am tried implementing some examples to test my understanding. Below is some simple code where I try to compute a simple sum (adding just zero each time) and compare the efficiency between parallelized code with openMP and the other code.
Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>

int main(){
    int N = 100000;
    int sum;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();


    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            sum += 0;
        }
    }

    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Parallel Elapsed time:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count()<<std::endl;


    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        sum += 0;
    }


    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Sequential Elapsed time:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count() <<std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Which yields:

```
Parallel Elapsed time:
351000
Sequential Elapsed time:
367000
```

Or around those figures after several executions. My question is where is the catch? It seems like everything is alright with my code.

Comment: I think that all you've learned is that the compiler has been clever enough to see that the entire loop is dead code - none of its results are used later in the program - and simply eliminated it.  `351000` is quite a big number but `0.000351seconds` is no time at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMP threading takes time so if your code does almost nothing in the part that has been parallized (here you just do a sum) the gain of making things in parallel is nullified by the time it takes create/select the openMP threads.

Furthermore in your code you use a reduction so all of you thread are most probably blocked waiting to access the shared `sum` variable. I am even surprise you get a performance gain using openMp in this specific case.

If the complexity of what you do in parallel increases, you will see a real gain in using OpenMP. (or any other parallel processing approach).

You could for instance try (as an "exercice") to sort independant vectors (without reduction) in parallel and sequentially to start seeing the benefits of openMP.

Comment: What makes you think that sum reduction is implemented using critical sections?

Comment: You are right reduction is done by creating local variables per thread (no overlap) which are then combined together when all thread are joined according to http://jakascorner.com/blog/2016/06/omp-for-reduction.html. It could have been done bumy using critical sections as well. I guess it might be implementation dependant.

Answer (score 2):

No. Your code is *not* alright!

First of all, the code is *ill-formed* because sum is not initialized to 0 if OpenMP is not enabled (did you enabled OpenMP using compiler arguments?). Thus, the sequential implementation leads to an *undefined behavior*. This is important because the [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf) states that:

> The OpenMP API is intended to support programs that will execute correctly both as parallel programs [...] and as sequential programs.

Moreover, the compiler is smart enough to *remove the useless addition* if you enabled compiler optimizations (did you?), as @HighPerformanceMark pointed out. Note that `sum` is not even read, so the compiler is free to totally ignore this variable. I advise you to look this [C++ conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk) explaining how to do correct benchmark and analyze performance.

In addition, you use [system_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) which is not monotonic. Indeed the C++ standard library documentation states that:

> on most systems, the system time can be adjusted at any moment

As a result, the timings you got can be totally wrong and even possibly negative! Please use [steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) which is more suited for measuring the wall-clock time.

Finally, threads may takes time to be created as @JeanMarcVolle mentioned. Thus, multithreading is useful only if the parallel work is quite big compared to the threading overhead. It is not worth it here. However, you can use SIMD-based parallelism instead, using a `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)` directive.

Comment: `sum` is not initialised to `0` even if OpenMP is enabled. The private copies of `sum` are initialised to `0` and then combined with the value `sum` had before the parallel region using the `+=` combiner.